# OUTPUT from Stored Procedure using Azure Mobile Custom API

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have a stored procedure that adds a new entry to a table and OUTPUTS the ID (as a nvarchar(255)) to @NewID. I can exec the procedure just fine to the asp.net backend using Postman but i can't get the OUTPUT... I have several Stored Procedures and they all work just fine just figure out how to capture the OUTPUT in the C# Post Method.

*For clarification I'm trying to exec a stored procedure and capture the output using entity framework over a web service. This is running on an Azure Mobile Service asp.net server.*

**Testing Stored Procedure**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddEnclosureKey]
(
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @SpecItemID nvarchar(255),
    @EnclosureType varchar(3) = 'XXX',
    @Comments varchar(50),
    @Elevation varchar(50),
    @ProvidedBy varchar(50),
    @InstalledBy varchar(50),
    @SiteID nvarchar(255) = 'CE359D6F-490B-45E4-BA14-72D20AB757FD',
    @NewID nvarchar(255) OUTPUT
)
AS
IF (@SpecItemID is not null or @SiteID is not null)
    BEGIN

        -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
        -- interfering with SELECT statements.
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        -- insert
        INSERT INTO dbo.SiteEnclosureKey(EnclosureKeyComments,EnclosureKeyType, EnclosureKeyElevation,EnclosureKeyProvidedBy,EnclosureKeyInstalledBy,EnclosureKeyItemID,EnclosureKeySiteID)
        VALUES (@Comments,IIF(@EnclosureType = 'XXX',dbo.AutoEnclosureKeyType(@SpecItemID),@EnclosureType), @Elevation, @ProvidedBy, @InstalledBy,@SpecItemID,@SiteID);

        IF @@IDENTITY > 0
        SELECT @NewID = Id FROM dbo.SiteEnclosures WHERE EnclosureID = @@IDENTITY;
        ELSE
        SET @NewID = null

    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        RETURN 0
    END
```

**Custom ApiController**

```
   [MobileAppController]
        public class AddEnclosureKeyController : ApiController
        {
            // POST api
            [HttpPost, Route("api/addenclosurekey")]
            public string Post(string item, string type="XXX", string comments="", string elevation="", string providedby="", string installedby="", string site="CE359D6F-490B-45E4-BA14-72D20AB757FD")
            {
                using (MIIToolsContext context = new MIIToolsContext())
                {
                    //get the database from the context
                    var database = context.Database;

                    //create the sql statement
                    var param1 = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@SpecItemID", item);
                    var param2 = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@EnclosureType", type);
                    var param3 = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Comments", comments);
                    var param4 = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Elevation", elevation);
                    var param5 = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@ProvidedBy", providedby);
                    var param6 = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@InstalledBy", installedby);
                    var param7 = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@SiteID", site);
                    var param8 = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter()
                    {
                        ParameterName = "@NewID",
                        Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output,
                        SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar,
                        Size = 255
                    };

                    //var result = database.SqlQuery<string>("dbo.AddEnclosureKey @SpecItemID , @EnclosureType , @Comments , @Elevation , @ProvidedBy , @InstalledBy , @SiteID , @NewID OUTPUT", param1, param2, param3, param4, param5, param6, param7, param8);

                    //return NewID.ToString();

                   database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC dbo.AddEnclosureKey @SpecItemID , @EnclosureType , @Comments , @Elevation , @ProvidedBy , @InstalledBy , @SiteID , @NewID OUTPUT", param1, param2, param3, param4, param5, param6, param7, param8);


                    return (string)param8.Value ?? "boo";

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: 1. What's `Id`'s type in database? may be you are having a casting issue. 2. Replace `SELECT @NewID =` with `SET @NewID =` and test.

Comment: The stored procedures works fine. I can get the @NewID output in SQL just fine. The problem is with the C# Api Post. There isn't alot of info or examples for it.

Comment: Well, you are doing it all wrong. You never shouldn't call a proc from the action method. You should have at lease your DAL. BUT, about the problem right now, did you test `SET`?

Comment: I don't really understand you with your double negative but I can't use a "SET" with a "FROM" and I'm calling the stored procedure from a web service so the only way i can call it is using a POST (if that is what you mean by "action method") thanks for trying to help but what you're saying doesn't seem to have any relevance to my actual question

Comment: My original question made it sound like I was having problems with the Stored Procedure itself returning the OUTPUT. It is working fine. I've edited the question to avoid that confusion again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out...
SQL SP parameters don't seem to be INPUT or OUTPUT but INPUT/OUTPUT.
So i changed the Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.InputOutput and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `OUTPUT` keyword to your execution line just after the `@NewID` part, and it will work:

```
database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC dbo.AddEnclosureKey @SpecItemID , @EnclosureType , @Comments , @Elevation , @ProvidedBy , @InstalledBy , @SiteID , @NewID OUTPUT", 
                            param1, param2, param3, param4, param5, param6, param7, param8);
```

But as I mentioned in comments, you have a lot to do with the code. You should never touch database inside an action - you need a data access layer. You better not to call procedures directly while using an ORM. You better change the `SELECT` part with `SET` in your procedure (`SET @param = (SELECT some FROM some blah blah blah)`) and so on. But they are not relevant to the question. The `OUTPUT` keyword will do the job.

Comment: Output doesn't work, have already tried that in many different variations, and again, can't use "SET" when using "FROM".

Comment: Azure app service uses the entity framework but it is very limited. For example you cant use things like stored procedures or relationships like you normally would in entity. So I have to do it this way using a custom web api accessing the data context. it's the only way I can find is possible. If you you know a better way than great, show me. Using OUTPUT after @NewID is how I originally tried it, param8 still always returns an empty string. Procedure returns output fine in sql directly.

Comment: The only problem I can see is the `OUTPUT` keyword. I tested the exact code with `OUTPUT` (and with `SET` of course) and it works just fine. So I haven't any other idea. **BUT**, you can use `SET` when using `FROM` as I pointed in answer: `SET @NewID = (SELECT Id FROM dbo.SiteEnclosures WHERE EnclosureID = @@IDENTITY);` Don't forget `( )` around `SELECT` statement.

Comment: Ok, I'll try the () but still, works fine in MSSMS, returns output just fine. When you say you tested it did you actually test it against an asp.net server with a Rest/OData call using something like Postman? I can do an HTTP Post and the SP will execute just fine, but i can't capture the OUPUT param. this is piece of cake if you are strictly talking SQL. I'm positive it is something I'm doing wrong within the C# code, if someone proves otherwise I'll buy them a coke.

Comment: SET = () didn't make any difference. this isn't a SQL problem

Comment: There is tow point: 1- about why you haven't result, which I said I have o idea. Yes I tested it in company's server and it just works. 2- You said its not possible to use `SET` with `FROM` which I said no, its possible. You just need to put the `SELECT` statement in `()`. Its a `best practice` approach which I recommended. Just like having a data access layer, etc. Hope find the problem. I can't see other possibilities.

Comment: Not to beat a dead horse too much but: This is running on the Entity Framework which if that isn't a DAL than I don't know what would be haha. SET vs SELECT, yes ANSI standard blah blah blah but still not the problem, not the question and I specifically said it was a test stored procedure. Thanks for spending your time with this, hopefully my answer will help someone in the future because there is almost ZERO complete documentation to do what i'm doing with the Azure App Service.